# Creating a (recursive) function in R

Tags: r, function

I have a dataframe:

```
objective=function(x) {
    for (i in 1: length(nutri_values[,2]))
    {
        objective(x)=objective(x)+ abs(nutri_values[i,2]-x)
    }
}
```

My nutri_values look like this:

```
1          95.58696
2     ABW  87.00000
4     ALB 117.39485
6     ARG  83.01671
9     AUS  94.52020
11    BEL  81.73263
```

and what I want to get is a function, sum{ abs (nutri_values[i,2]-x)}, in order to define an optimization problem.

But, I get the following error message:

```
 Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
```

Comment: Why did that error message come from?

Comment: from the command 
    objective(3)

Comment: So, you are trying to define a function `objective` that you are trying to call inside itself? And you try to store the result of this undefined function inside the same undifined function?

Comment: Do you mean: `objective = function(x) {sum( abs(nutri_values[,2]-x))}; objective(3)`

Comment: @Pascal
I wanted to create a function to sum it absolute values. I thought that using that for loop and the calling of the function at each iteration it will add the result of iteration i to the previous one.

Comment: @csgillespie
 it works... thank you. I am kind of lost at the moment. (don t know why i didn t try that, i was thinking coordinate by coordinate)

Comment: Does anyone know how to plot this function?
I tried     plot(objective) and curve(objective)...

Comment: You probably mixed up `[]` and `()`. Prevous Matlab users are sometimes lost. And you need to provide a input to the function.

Comment: @Pascal
This is what i tried: curve(objective, from=40, to=110) this is the error message Error in curve(objective, from = 40, to = 110) : 'expr' did not evaluate to an object of length 'n' In addition: Warning message: In nutri_values[, 2] - x : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length –

Comment: Probably not the best solution, but change the `objective` function such as it takes 2 arguments `x` and `y` (`function(x,y)`) and `nutri_values[,2]` by `y` inside the function. Create a vector `x=40:110` and a vector `y=nutri_values[,2]`. Use `sapply(x, objective, y)`. I guess it is possible to `Vectorize` the function.